# Debugging JavaScript code on Sublime using mocha

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2, npm, mocha.js, javascript-debugger

I have written some test cases and executing them using mocha. I am using sublime as the editor. When I run the test cases (using mocha), I want to add debugging points and want to see what is happening. If not SubLime, is there any way to execute these test case on browser and add breakpoints in browser?

If this approach is not practical what other alternatives I have?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You can use [node-debug](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-debug):

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Then:

```
node-debug _mocha test.js
```

It will open Chrome with the Web Inspector, ready to debug your app.

One problem you'll have is that, as the test isn't started yet, your files won't be loaded. You can add `debugger;` statements in your code to force breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. After installing the package and running the command, I got error saying "Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: Error: connect econnrefused. Is code running with --debug port 5858? "